# REST how to properly deal with relationships

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

Suppose i have a resource (say Class) which has-many Student resources.

```
Class
  id: 1
  name: A
  subject: Maths

Student
  name: Foo
  surname: Bar
  class: [?]
```

I have 2 scenarios to deal with.

**[1]: Insert a new Student**

In this case better solution would be to add a class id and post the resource as

```
Student
  name: Foo
  surname: Bar
  class: 1
```

This makes server side processing really easy, since my resource is mostly a db table mirror.

**[2]: List Students, each with his own class.** For example:

```
Student Name | Student Surname | Student Class | Class Subject
Foo1           Bar               A               Math
Foo2           Bar               A               Math
Foo3           Bar               B               Science
```

Here the id representation is not enough to display every data i need, so i could

- (a) Load students, with class id, and load class data in a separate call
- (b) Load students, with embedded class data

In case (a), one more remote call is needed to load class data because my students would look like

```
Students: [
  {name: Foo1, surname: Bar, class: 1},
  {name: Foo2, surname: Bar, class: 1},
  {name: Foo3, surname: Bar, class: 2},
]
```

Case (b) seems to be more appropriate, since my students would look like

```
Students: [
  {name: Foo1, surname: Bar, class: {id:1, name: A, subject: Maths}},
  {name: Foo2, surname: Bar, class: {id:1, name: A, subject: Maths}},
  {name: Foo3, surname: Bar, class: {id:2, name: B, subject: Science}},
]
```

If i choose (a), i am ok with scenario [1] and i have overhead with scenario [2] (additional calls to fill class data).

If i choose (b) i am ok with scenario [2], but i have problems with the Student Resource representation of scenario [1], since i should post a complete Class resource in the payload, like this:

```
Student
  name: Foo
  surname: Bar
  class: {id:1, name: B, subject: Science}
```

Question1: What would be the best approach?

Question2: Can you point any good reading about this?

**== EDIT ==**

Question3: What is **not** RESTful in the above?

Comment: These aren't really questions about REST. Can you think of more appropriate tags?

Comment: uhm why not? i am asking about a proper rest approach to represent resources

Comment: So what media type are you defining to represent said resources? What kind of link relations are you going to use? These are the questions which pertain to REST-style architectures. You appear to be asking questions about how to send data in batches across the wire, which is fine... but really hasn't anything to do with REST. In fact, you could argue that using IDs that aren't URLs isn't RESTful at all.

Comment: You got a point. What im lookin for is how to make these examples RESTful, see edit pls.

Comment: 'i should post a complete Class resource in the payload' Why do you think that? A `Student` is complete without any class.

Comment: As far as i know the same representation you use when reading resources (i.e. GET /resource/1) should be the very same when you write them (i.e. POST /resource). Isn't it?

Comment: @brazorf: see my answer. They do not need to be.

Answer (score 0):

Case A seems better.

- Your Student stores a *foreign key* to the class he is attending.
- Updating Class information is easy, since Students store only the foreign key (e.g. no need to cascade updates to all student objects)

I suggest you study good old-fashioned [*relational database design*](http://rdbms.ca/database/design.html). Even if you are not using them, you will learn a great deal about data.

Answer (score 0):

Using your example, here is how I might do it using JSON and HAL.

A root page:

**Request:**

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

**Response:**

```
200 OK
Content-Type: application/hal+json

{
  "_links": {
    "self": { "href": "/" },
    "students": { "href": "/students" },
    "classes": { "href": "/classes" },
    "students-with-classes": { "href": "/students?expand" },
  }
}
```

Creating a new student would be documented on the `students` relation via posting to the provided href. Presumably I would have previously followed the `classes` link relation to get the link to class A so that I can include it when adding a user.

**Request:**

```
POST /students HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{
  name: "Foo",
  surname: "Bar",
  class-link: "/classes/1"
}
```

**Response:**

```
201 Created
Location: http://example.com/students/10
```

Listing the collection of students (following the `students-with-classes` relation);

**Request:**

```
GET /students?expand HTTP/1.1
```

**Response:**

```
200 OK
Content-Type: application/hal+json

{
  "_links": {
    self: { href: "/students" }
  },
  "_embedded": {
    "students": [
      {
        "_links": {
          "self": { "href": "/students/1" },
          "classes": [ { "href": "/classes/1", "title": "A" } ]
        },
        "name": "Foo1",
        "surname": "Bar"
      },
      {
        "_links": {
          "self": { "href": "/students/2" },
          "classes": [ { "href": "/classes/1", "title": "A" } ]
        },
        "name": "Foo2",
        "surname": "Bar"
      },
      {
        "_links": {
          "self": { "href": "/students/3" },
          "classes": [ { "href": "/classes/2", "title": "B" } ]
        },
        "name": "Foo3",
        "surname": "Bar"
      }
    ],
    "classes": [
      {
        "_links": {
          "self": { "href": "/classes/1" }
        },
        "name": "A",
        "subject": "Math"
      },
      {
        "_links": {
          "self": { "href": "/classes/2" }
        },
        "name": "A",
        "subject": "Science"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

A couple of things to note:

- I `POST` generic `application/json` data but retrieve `application/hal+json`. The representations do not need to be the same in each direction.
- I use the URI as the resource identifier for the Class to link to, not an artificial external ID. Such an ID *may* be part of a that URI, but the client should never make that assumption.